# call client method from server without invoke server method from client in swiftR

Tags: ios, swift, signalr, swiftr

I am using swiftR. I have one situation that when in 30 second client don't ask to question and invoke server method, server should call client method.

In my code when user ask to question call this method from server :

```
void Daily_Answer_Save3(string Token, long DailyID, long QuestionID, long OptionID)
```

and in server side call

```
Daily_Answer_Save3_Result
```

from client.

But I have a problem when client don't ask to question and `Daily_Answer_Save3` is not called, in this case first this method should call from server and in then call client method from server.

But when I put breakPoint in hub. on callback after 30 second this callback not call and i don't get any result. Where is my problem and how can fix it?

Comment: Does anyone have any idea about it.

Comment: You probably need timer on the server and and invoke the call if needed. Otherwise how server is supposed to know it should invoke a client method?